# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в первом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

А насчёт боли в груди, это дело моих рук, точнее руки. Я  сделала всё, чтобы спасти тебя. 
Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в первом предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***А насчёт боли в груди, это дело моих рук, точнее руки.***

Запятая ставится, это упрощенный вариант сложного предложения вида: *А что касается боли в груди, то это дело моих рук.*

Сравнить: *Что касается меня, то я выступал на сцене дважды.*

Этот тип предложений относят к СПП  особого вида, а придаточное называют  **акцентирующим**. Оно  имеет признаки придаточных трех видов (по значению и структуре):  присоединительного, изъяснительного и местоименного.